# How do I complete a Career if it doesn't have enough Skills?

Tags: wfrp-4e

The book has this to say:

> To complete a Career, you must have the number of Advances listed below in all your Career level's Characteristics and in eight of your Career level's available skills. You must also have at least 1 Talent from your current Career level. Skills and Talents you have gained from advancement prior to entering your current Career count towards this.

This sounds pretty straight forward. To move from level 2 to level 3 in a Career, I need 10 advances. Taking an Apothecary as an example, I would need to get:

- 10 advances in Toughness, Dexterity, Initiative and Intelligence.
- Either Criminal, Dealmaker, Etiquette (Guilder) or Pharmacist talent
- 10 advances in 8 skills, out of these skills: Charm, Haggle, Lore (Science), Gossip, Language (Guilder), Perception

Those of you who have taken the Lore (Mathematics) will note that the available skills in the second level of Apothecary number only 6. This would make it impossible to ever complete this Career level, as I can't have 10 advances in 8 skills, if I can only level up 6 skills.

So how can I ever meet this requirement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It took me a while of flipping back and forth in the book, but unlike Talents, which are limited to the current Career level you are on, Career Skills are not actually limited to the level you are currently on.

Page 47 under Skill Advances tells you that you can always learn Skills from lower levels of your Career. So while the completing a Career text states "eight of your Career level's available Skills", that also includes the skills from previous Career levels, as those are still available to you.